# CSS change only for one row in table

Tags: html, css

I need to change the width property of one row in a table without affecting the width of other rows below it.Is it possible?

Edit1:Sorry for incomplete question. How to do it and which property to use?

I have tried using the :

1. nth-child property but it is effecting the whole rows in that column.
2. applying style to that particular row by assigning a class to it but both the methods didn't work.

I have a 3x3 table in which i wanted to change the width of, say first row without changing the width of second and third row. Something as shown in the picture:

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is possible

Comment: You just want to know if it’s possible? Ya. It is.

Comment: if it's a table, then no. a table means same width. If you want different width use something else

Comment: @Claire I would really like to know how, it can be very useful.

Comment: @AlonEitan if the answer is *yes* it can be useful to add as answer. I my self want to know how.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Sorry for the late reply - You can do it by adding `position:absolute;width:<any-width>;` to the last cell in some row - So it will get bigger, and it's a terrible practice that should be avoided, but it will work

Answer (score 1):

You can use `colspan` attribute of `td`

Try this:

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
  /*added only for better style of example*/
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" >colspan 2</td> <!--this is the corresponding column-->
    <td>normal column</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>normal column</td>
    <td>normal column</td>
    <td>normal column</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>normal column</td>
    <td>normal column</td>
    <td>normal column</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Replicating exactly(without content):

```css
table,th,td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2" ></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> </td>
  <td> </td>
  <td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> </td>
  <td> </td>
  <td> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Refer: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp

Hope it helps!

Comment: Really? -1 for this answer? Stack is indeed a rough place

Comment: using colspan gave the desired output for me. Thank you.

Comment: @chandu11235813 happy to help :) Please upvote or accept my answer for future readers reference, if you feel it was helpful